# PostgreSQL now() and daylight saving

Tags: postgresql, dst

We are having an issue with daylight savings in PostgreSQL 9.0.10. In the attempt to use the OS timezone files structure, we replace the PostgreSQL's files with a link to OS timezone files (and renamed the original ones)

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/pgsql/share/timezone/Brazil
/usr/local/pgsql/share/timezone/Brazil -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Brazil/
```

Querying the database, everything looks ok:

```
=> SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names where name like '%Brazil%';
           name            | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst
---------------------------+--------+------------+--------
 Brazil.original/DeNoronha | FNT    | -02:00:00  | f
 Brazil.original/East      | BRST   | -02:00:00  | t
 Brazil.original/West      | AMT    | -04:00:00  | f
 Brazil.original/Acre      | AMT    | -04:00:00  | f
 Brazil/DeNoronha          | -02    | -02:00:00  | f
 Brazil/East               | BRT    | -03:00:00  | f
 Brazil/West               | -04    | -04:00:00  | f
 Brazil/Acre               | -05    | -05:00:00  | f

=> show timezone;
  TimeZone
-------------
Brazil/East
```

"Brazil/East", as shown above, is -03, with DST false. But then we get this:

```
=> select now(), now() AT TIME ZONE 'Brazil/East';
              now              |          timezone
-------------------------------+----------------------------
2018-10-21 11:25:51.300744-02 | 2018-10-21 11:25:51.300744
```

We were expecting to see "2018-10-21 10:25:51.300744-03" and not this date in 
"-02".

Any ideas about what we are missing here?

Comment: If you are using an unsupported Postgres version, then why aren't you at least using the latest minor release which would be 9.0.23? As each minor release is always shipped with the latest TZ files -  maybe those from 2015 already contain the fixes you want (9.0.10 was release in 2012 - so there are three years between them).

Comment: We have a scenario where we can´t do this upgrade. The change of DST date was done by Brazil government only 2 weeks ago.

Comment: [Quote from the homepage](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/): "*For minor releases, **the community considers not upgrading to be riskier than upgrading***" your current version is missing 3 years of bugfixes - some of them could even lead to data corruption (but indeed it won't solve your DST problem)

Comment: Yeah. Anyway, thank you for the advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Replacing files in a PostgreSQL installation is not the correct and supported way to deal with that, so it is not surprising that you get strange results.

You should rebuild PostgreSQL and configure it using `--with-system-tzdata`, as stated in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/install-procedure.html).

But of course you shouldn't be using version 9.0, this has been out of support for about 3 years.

Comment: We have a scenario where we can´t do this upgrade.

Comment: Well, then obviously the data are not very important to you. In that case you don't have to worry about upgrading.

Comment: By far, this is not reason we can´t upgrade. But thank you anyway for you time!

Comment: I mean, even if you don't want to upgrade, you should rebuild PostgreSQL if you want to use different time zone files.